# Camera Changes Its Position After Rendering

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I have set up a scene and the camera is in place but when I render the scene, rendered image is in a completely different place.

Here is a video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4S33z5XcMIsc3M0UmZzQlZhb3M

Comment: With the information you posted is very hard to help you. No one knows anything about your scene but you. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information, and add images that shows the full viewport on camera view and an image of what you are getting on the render. Please specify if you have more than one camera on the scene.

Comment: In the 3dviewport press numpad 0 to see the scene from the camera, does that match what you render? Check the location/rotation properties of the camera to see if there are any keyframes (the location will be shaded green or yellow) that will move the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera has a keyframe on the first frame of your animation, and that is what is being rendered. 
If you move the camera but don't record a new keyframe the camera will reset to that keyframe at frame 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, the camera has a keyframe, indicated by the yellow line (here inside the green line) in the timeline. Go to the first frame, select your camera and press Alt+I to remove the keyframe.

Answer (score 0):

I just applied a *Displacement* modifier over the modifier tab. The modifier was off for the real time viewport so the displacement was only visible in the final render.

That could also be a solution, if someone also forgot about a *Displacement* modifier, because in the viewport shading with the activated render mode the *Displacement* modifier would also be invisible.